# Symfony 4 Validator don't read value from inputs

Tags: php, forms, symfony, validation

### Problem:

Validator ignores the values written in the fields of the form (ignores *name*, *id* and *title*, for example) Am I doing something wrong?

.

### Details:

**1.** I created a basic HTML form in Symfony 4 without using the Forms component:

```
<form action="{{ path("register") }}" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="text" name="email">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted">
    <button type="submit">Create user</button>
</form>
```

**2.** Now, before insert the user into the DB, I'm trying to validate the form data using Symfony's Validator component, but remember: I'm not using the Forms component and this is the way I'm doing it:

```
use App\Entity\User
use /-- ... --/

class SecurityController extends Controller {

     /**
      * @Route("/register", name="register")
      */

      public function showRegisterPage(Request $request) {

         if ($request->request->get("submitted") !== null) {

             $user = new User();
             $validator = $this->get("validator");
             $errors = $validator->validate($user);

             if (count($errors) === 0) {
                 /-- Insert the user in the database. --/
             }
         }

         return $this->render("security/register.html.twig");
      }
}
```

**3.** To validate the data, Validator uses an Entity called User that contains, among other things, the validation rules - only **NotBlank()** for now:

```
namespace App\Entity

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 */

class User implements UserInterface {

     /**
      * @ORM\Id
      * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
      * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
      */
     private $id;

     /**
      * @ORM\Column(type="string")
      * @Assert\NotBlank()
      */
     private $username;

     /**
      * @ORM\Column(type="string")
      * @Assert\NotBlank()
      */
     private $password;

     /**
      * @ORM\Column(type="string")
      * @Assert\NotBlank()
      */
      private $email;

      /-- Getters and Setter here --/
}
```

I need to know why Validator does not recognize the form fields; the Debug bar shows that there are indeed 3 empty fields. I thought Validator used the *name* of the field, I also tried the *id* and the *title*, all failed.

How can I take the data from the fields to validate them with Validator without using the Forms component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your code, there is absolutely no interaction between the user entity and the form. So regardless of what is entered into the form, the user entity will stay *blank*.

Meaning at least, you'd need to populate the user entity *by hand*:

```
if ($request->request->get("submitted") !== null) {

    $user = new User();

    // populate:
    $user->setUsername($request->request->get('username'));
    //...

    $validator = $this->get("validator");
    $errors = $validator->validate($user);

    if (count($errors) === 0) {
        /-- Insert the user in the database as above. --/
    }
}
```

Note that this would not help you actually show the validation errors inside the view. For this you'd need to pass the `$errors` to the view and manually check each field. But all this could be done (more or less) automatically using the [form component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html).

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have no problems populating the data, what I want is to validate the information BEFORE inserting in the DB.

I understand the variable $ errors in the view, do not worry about that. All I'm looking for is to avoid using the Forms component.

Comment: @JuanNicolás Well then you have your answer, just populate the entity with the form data and validate.

Comment: @JuanNicolás Or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: OMG, I just understood what you wanted to teach me. I checked the official documentation (as for the tenth time) and everything made sense. Yoshi, thank you, you were always right, it was me who with my inexperience was not able to see the solution. 8 hours in a row behind this and the solution was so simple.